# Open file from path using partial name

Tags: excel, vba

I found the code to open a file from a path (referring to a cell), as well as how to open a file when the complete file name is unknown, however, I'm unable to do both. Is this possible?

Open File From Path:

```
Dim google_ads_report As Workbook
Dim FromPath As String

'   Get path from cell C14 on Report tab
FromPath = Workbooks("Monthly Report - Master.xlsm").Sheets("Macros").Range("C14")

'   Make sure there is a backslash at the end of the from path
If Right(FromPath, 1) <> "\" Then FromPath = FromPath & "\"


'Set wkb = ThisWorkbook
Set google_ads_report = Workbooks.Open(FromPath & "hi.xlsx")
```

Open File with partial Name (because it changes every month):

```
GA_Transactions = VBA.FileSystem.Dir("C:\Users\tom\Desktop\Analytics Google Ads Revenue - Monthly*.xlsx")

Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\tom\Desktop\" & GA_Transactions
```

Weirdly, the partial file open code needs the directory both times which after coming across this problem and thinking about it, is strange, right?

I'm assuming there's a way to do it but I can't seem to do it/find it.

Thanks!

Comment: What are the variations on a monthly basis?

Comment: `VBA.FileSystem.Dir` only returns the file name, not the path, so yes you need the directory.

Comment: Hi @Dean, dates which should be easy to add, but other platforms have random numbers appended to the report name hence looking for this fix.

BigBen ah ok makes sense in that case.

Comment: But, what is happening with your code? Does it return an error? If not, does it return a wrong file name? If yes, this way of using wildcard returns **the first match found**, if many are available...

Comment: @FaneDuru I got different errors depending how i tried to format the code, mostly it says "sorry, we couldn't find ....."

Comment: What does this line `Debug.Print VBA.FileSystem.Dir("C:\Users\tom\Desktop\Analytics Google Ads Revenue - Monthly*.xlsx")` return in Immediate Window? You must debug your code in small steps. Does it return a file name? Otherwise, the path you supplied is wrong, or there is no any file name starting with "Analytics Google Ads Revenue - Monthly" in that specific folder. There is no other possibility, I think...

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is looping through the specified folder, and checking if the file name has the required month text. See below code (not tested, but should point you in the right direction).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Open_File()
    
    Dim fs As Object, sf As Object, file As Variant
    Dim sFileName As String
    
    
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    Set sf = fs.GetFolder("C:\Users\tom\Desktop\")
    
    sFileName = "Analytics Google Ads Revenue - Monthly"
    
    For Each file In sf.Files
        If InStr(file.Name, sFileName) > 0 Then
            
            'file found - now execute open method
            
            Exit For
        End If
    Next file
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @dean, much appreciated

Comment: Hey @Tom, no problem. If this worked, please mark this as the answer to close the ticket. Cheers!